# Make a card flip from bottom origin without moving vertically

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

I'm trying to create a rolodex type thing, which would involve cards rotating on their x axis, using transform-origin:bottom;

It's kind of working, but during the animation the card moves vertically, so it takes away from the "stationary flip down" effect.

How can I make the card rotate from its bottom, while remaining stationary

It's also lacking a 3d perspective. Any suggestions on how to make the card look as if it is falling towards you (z axis) as it rotates?

HAML:

```
.top
  .rolo-w
    #f1_card
      .front.face
        %h1 Lorem Ipsum
      .back.face.center
.bottom
```

CSS:

```
.top{
  position:relative;
  height: 50vh;
}
.rolo-w{
  width:400px;
  height: 200px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  perspective: 1000;
}

#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
.top:hover #f1_card {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin:bottom;


}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

}
.face.front{
  background: url("http://placehold.it/400x200");
}
.face.back {
  background-color:green;
  display: block;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
h1{ margin:0; text-align: center}
```

[Pen here](http://codepen.io/jhlavac/pen/PwKoZz)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from having transform-origin set only on the hovered state.
Then, the transition invloves *changing* the transform-origin, and this isn't what you want. move transform-origin to the base style:

```
#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
.top:hover #f1_card {
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
```

also, perspective must have units

```
perspective: 1000px;
```

And the final angle must be negative if you want it to fall towards you

result:

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNZNZx)